# Select Random Cell In A Range Only If It Has A Value - Excel

Tags: excel, random, vba

So here is the following VBA code I'm currently using. It works perfectly but I need to expand the range to check additional cells but some of those cells could contain empty cells and I don't want to select those.

Is there a way to bypass those empty cells?

```
Dim RNG1 As Range
Set RNG1 = Range("H1:H30")

Dim randomCell1 As Long
    randomCell1 = Int(Rnd * RNG1.Cells.Count) + 1

With RNG1.Cells(randomCell1)
.Select
'will do something else here, like copy the cell, fill the cell with a color, etc
End With
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should pick only non-empty cells:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim RNG1 As Range, r As Range, c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    Set RNG1 = Range("H1:H30")
    For Each r In RNG1
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            c.Add r
        End If
    Next r
    Dim N As Long
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, c.Count)
    Set rselect = c.Item(N)
    rselect.Select
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

This is an example of a general technique.  To make a random pick from a **subset** of a range, collect the subset and pick from the Collection.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late but no harm in posting :)

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim NErng
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = Range("A1:A15")

For Each cel In rng
    If Len(cel) <> 0 Then
        If IsArray(NErng) Then
            ReDim Preserve NErng(UBound(NErng) + 1)
            NErng(UBound(NErng)) = cel.Address
        ElseIf IsEmpty(NErng) Then
            NErng = cel.Address
        Else
            NErng = Array(NErng, cel.Address)
        End If
    End If
Next

i = Int((UBound(NErng) - LBound(NErng) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(NErng))
Debug.Print Range(NErng(i)).Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If the values in column H were `XlConstants` then something like this using `SpecialCells`

```
Sub Option_B()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lngCel As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("H1:H30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim randomCell1 As Long
randomCell1 = Int(Rnd * rng1.Cells.Count) + 1

For Each rng2 In rng1.Cells
'kludgy as there will be multiple areas in a SpecialFCells range with blank cells
lngCel = lngCel + 1
    If lngCel = randomCell1 Then
        Application.Goto rng2
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT -- @brettdj is right. This is adjusted to better answer the "skip these cells" question.

Try this out:

```
DangThisCellIsBlank:
RandomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG1.Cells.Count) + 1

With RNG1.Cells(RandomCell)
    If .Value <> "" Then
        'do stuff
    Else
        'go back and pick another cell
        GoTo DangThisCellIsBlank
    End If
End With
```

Comment: doesnt address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `IsEmpty(RNG1.Cells(randomCell1))`

```
Dim RNG1 As Range
Set RNG1 = Range("H1:H30")

Dim randomCell1 As Long
randomCell1 = Int(Rnd * RNG1.Cells.Count) + 1

'Keep Looping until you find a non empty cell
Do While IsEmpty(RNG1.Cells(randomCell1))
    randomCell1 = Int(Rnd * RNG1.Cells.Count) + 1
Loop
'================================================

With RNG1.Cells(randomCell1)
    .Select
    'will do something else here, like copy the cell, fill the cell with a color, etc
End With
```

Comment: wont work as `RNG1.Cells.Count` will always = 30 regardless of how many blank cells there are.